# Excel rounding puzzle

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I enter the following numbers in Excel in Column B, rows 1-4:

```
-1,900,050,002.00
        40,000.40
        10,000.70
 1,900,000,000.90
```

In Cell B6, I have a formula =SUM(B1:B5). B6 is formatted to show 10 decimal places.

This shows zero as expected.

But, if I enter 0 in cell B5, the value in B6 changes to: 0.0000002384
If I remove the 0 from B5, B6 goes back to showing zero.

Why is this?

The before and after images are shown here:

Before:

[image: Before entering 0 in B5]

After:

[image: After entering 0 in B5]

Comment: [this may prove useful](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, yeah, the magnitude of the number when the zero value is included is floating point error, and the result is formatted with enough decimal places to show it.  But why does adding zero cause the error value to be displayed, and it isn't displayed without it?

Comment: Interestingly, this only occurs if the 0 is last. If you change the order of the 5 values so the 0 is in any other position, you get 0 as a result.